# Revising BASH script to work on whatever file I tell it to

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I've written a bash script to run a series of commands, culminating in a file called `DataAudit.txt`. It works great... if the file I am working with happens to be called `file.csv`.

I'm very new to all of this and not sure how to write the script so it can work on whichever file I want to audit.

The script, called `audit.sh`, lives in a folder called `PurgatoryCSV` and the idea is that I would drop a file in there, run the script, and move the file to the next step in my workflow.

I would be grateful for any help I could get with this roadblock.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "DATA AUDIT

------------
COLUMN NAMES
------------

" > DataAudit.txt
csvcut -n file.csv >> DataAudit.txt
echo -n "

---------------------------------------
FIRST TEN ROWS OF FIRST FIVE COLUMNS 
---------------------------------------

" >> DataAudit.txt
csvcut -c 1,2,3,4,5 file.csv | head -n 10 >> DataAudit.txt
echo -n "

------------
COLUMN STATS
------------

" >> DataAudit.txt
csvcut file.csv | csvstat >> DataAudit.txt
echo -n "

---END AUDIT" >> DataAudit.txt
```

Comment: I provided an answer below, but I'm not sure I touched on what you want to do with PurgatoryCSV. If my solution isn't clear enough, please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you may want create a crontab entry that runs this script in a timely manner. The inputfile entry would be a `file.csv` and the final command of the script could rename the inputfile so that it's not processed again. Perhaps appending a timestamp (the same could be applied to the outputfile as backup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables that are passed in from the command line: `$1` for the first, `$2` for the second, etc. It looks like you have two variables here, the `file.csv` and `DataAudit.txt`

If you replace `file.csv` with `$1` and `DataAudit.txt` with `$2`, you can now execute your script by doing:

```
./audit.sh myotherfile.csv MyOtherAudit.txt
```

---

Alternatively for more readability, it is common to assign these into named variables at the top of your script:

```
INPUTFILE=$1
OUTPUTFILE=$2
```

Then, in your code you can reference these with `$INPUTFILE` and `$OUTPUTFILE`

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not part of the question, a here-document in these circumstances provides an elegant and clearer implementation of the above script, removing error prone repetition:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage () { echo "${0##*/} inputfile outputfile"; exit 1; }

(($#==2)) || usage

INPUTFILE="$1"
OUTPUTFILE="$2"

cat <<EOF >$OUTPUTFILE # all that follows upto 'EOF' will go to the outputfile
DATA AUDIT

------------
COLUMN NAMES
------------

$(csvcut -n $INPUTFILE)

---------------------------------------
FIRST TEN ROWS OF FIRST FIVE COLUMNS 
---------------------------------------

$(csvcut -c 1,2,3,4,5 $INPUTFILE | head -n 10)

------------
COLUMN STATS
------------

$(csvcut $INPUTFILE | csvstat )

---END AUDIT
EOF
```

Comment: Might as well change it to simply print to stdout, let the user specify a redirect if output to a file is desired.

Comment: @tripleee - By making the second argument optional and changing `OUTPUTFILE=">$2"` this can easily be achieved.

Comment: This worked, but generated an error that I'd love to understand: `close failed in file object destructor: sys.excepthook is missing lost sys.stderr`. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` {inputFile} {outputFile}"
  exit 1
fi

InputFile="$1"
OutputFile="$2"

echo -n "DATA AUDIT

------------
COLUMN NAMES
------------

" > "$OutputFile"
csvcut -n "$InputFile" >> "$OutputFile"
echo -n "

---------------------------------------
FIRST TEN ROWS OF FIRST FIVE COLUMNS 
---------------------------------------

" >> "$OutputFile"
csvcut -c 1,2,3,4,5 "$InputFile" | head -n 10 >> "$OutputFile"
echo -n "

------------
COLUMN STATS
------------

" >> "$OutputFile"
csvcut "$InputFile" | csvstat >> "$OutputFile"
echo -n "

---END AUDIT" >> "$OutputFile"
```

Call the script as

```
audit.sh InputFile OutputFile
```

i.e.

```
audit.sh file.csv DataAudit.txt
```

You would have to do more validations about the filenames being passed.